# How to create a generic DB connection service

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, mybatis

I have to create a Micro service that is able to connect to a DB and should not have any Entity Classes, I do not want this micro service to be DB specific, I want it to be able to connect to any DB given.

How it can be done ? Is it even possible with entity classes ?

Comment: The question is too broad.

Comment: Since you have to connec to a DB at the end your service will be DB specific. Why don't you try a factory pattern?

Answer (score -1):

you can make a "general" class to create connections

```
 class DbConnector {
    private final String url;
    private final String driver;
    private final String user;
    private final String pass;

    public DbConnector(String url, String driver, String user, String pass) {

        this.url = url;
        this.driver = driver;
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public Connection connection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(this.driver);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.pass);
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
Connection conn = new DbConnector(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_oopproject",
            "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
            "user","12345"
    ).connection();
```

It must be improved according your needings, but it is a start point.